# How can I fix this error message in D365 (Quantity cannot be invoiced because inventory transactions with a status of Received are insufficient

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to see how to fix this error in D365 when a Project Invoice proposal is trying to Post. There are no inventory for an item that this invoice is coming from. I checked the item model groups and tested different scenarios. A customer returned the items and now I'm trying to take them out of our transactions for the Sales Order from a project.

There is no packing slip or anything that ties to the return nor an RMA issued. Where am I not looking in D365 or have not clicked on to remove this error message from allowing the project invoice to post?